# Forbidden nikah

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

Assalam alaikum. My father passed away four years back. After that, my mom got married to another man who already has a daughter. Am i allowed to marry the daughter islamically

Comment: Are those the only forbidden marriages in islam mentioned in the surah(nisa'i), and my question is not part of the ayah. So is it also forbidden or not. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Wa alaikom salam wa rahmato allah wa barakatoh , yes you are allowed to marry the daughter islamically

Comment: Shukran Jazakumullah bi khair